# Hiding dangerous things in slim template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

I allow my users to enter a slim template on my site, then I compile it using:

`Slim::Template.new { ..customer_template_here.. }`

but I want to remove dangerous things that my users shouldn't have access to like "Rails.application". Is there a way to limit what is available ruby-wise in the Slim template?

Comment: Don't think you can - consider a templating language designed for this purpose such as liquid.

Comment: I used to use liquid but I had a hard time finding answers for common issues.